# plot two matrices both of (4*36 double) size in mat lab

Tags: matlab, matrix, plot

I would like to plot two matrices both of (4*36 double) size. The first contains rho and the second contains depths for the 36 locations

well I looked into surf but it reads two arrays and one matrix rather than two matrices and yes I would like to plot them as column graph

here is an example

```
rho= magic(36);
rho(5:1:end,:)=[];
D= magic(36);
D(5:1:end,:)=[];
D=sort(depth);
```

So right now the matrix rho contains the densities for the 36 location at four different depths. The matrix D contains the four different depths at which the reading at rho is found. The first element in the first matrix corresponds to the first element in the second matrix and so on
in the end what I would like to have is the 36 column with the different reading from (rho) plotted against appropriate depth in (D)

I hope I helped make it clearer somehow

Comment: Have you looked at `surf()`? Otherwise, it's hard to guess what you want with the info you provided. Consider providing examples, link to examples etc...

Comment: How do you want to plot them? Four line graphs? Surface plot? Pie chart? As it is you have made a statement and not even asked a question. I realize this is your first question... but ask yourself "can anyone help me with the information I have given"? "Do they know what rho and depth mean to me?" etc...

Comment: Thanks Floris for the comment I made some changes and I hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

Simple example of plotting four sets of X and Y data:

```
X = repmat(1:36, [4 1]);
Y(1,:) = rand(1,36);
Y(2,:) = 0.2 * (1:36);
Y(3,:) = 5 * sin(linspace(-pi,pi,36));
Y(4,:) = 0.1 * (1:36).^2;

figure
plot(X', Y')
```

This results in
[image]

Note - in order to get four series to plot like this, the data has to be in COLUMNS. The original data was in 4x36 matrix, so it was in ROWS. I used the transpose operator (apostrophe - `X'` rather than just `X`) to get the data organized in columns.

Maybe this helps...